# Gaseous ionic compound = plasma?

Tags: states-of-matter, ions

I know that ionic compounds have a boiling point and a melting point. Like for example sodium chloride melts into individual NaCl units at 801 degrees Celsius. It boils at 1,413 degrees Celsius. Since plasma is essentially ionized gas and ionic bonds break at very high temperatures, do ionic compounds skip the gas phase when they boil and go straight from liquid to plasma from the ions separating?

Comment: Boiling sodium chloride would create a vapor of sodium chloride molecules. Since there is no current flow within the vapor, then there can be no plasma.

Comment: Perhaps better suited for http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/?